# Perl script to send e-mail reading file content

Tags: perl

Wrote a Perl script to extract contents from 2 arrays and store it to a file **(out.log)** in the below format

```
open my $fh, ">", "out.log" or die "Cannot open out.log: $!";
for my $i (0..$#arr_1){
    print $fh "$arr_1[$i]\t$arr_2[$i]\@gmail.com\n"; }
close $fh; 


12345 joe@gmail.com
67890 jack@gmail.com
45678 john@gmail.com
```

Now by reading the out.log file content , I have to send e-mail to joe@gmail.com with e-mail body content

```
Your balance is:12345
```

to, jack@gmail.com

```
Your balance is:67890
```

to,john@gmail.com

```
Your balance is:45678
```

I can read the log file and form the mail body content like below but unsure how to achieve the above mentioned scenario.

```
my $mail_body = "Your balance is:\n";
{
  local $/ = undef;
  open FILE, "file" or die "...: !$";
  $mail_body .= <FILE>;
  close FILE;
}
```

Looking forward for help .Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? How to read one file from an input file, or how to send an email?

Comment: My requirement is to send e-mail by reading the out.log file. Account balance and e-mail recipients are available in the log file 

`12345 joe@gmail.com
67890 jack@gmail.com
45678 john@gmail.com`

I have to send e-mail to individual e-mail ids with e-mail body content like below:

to,
`joe@gmail.com

Your balance is:12345`

to,
`jack@gmail.com

Your balance is:67890`

to,
`john@gmail.com

Your balance is:45678`

Comment: @Vigs You haven't really answered choroba's question.  Can you tell us -- (1) Do you know how to read the file(s) as needed? (2) Do you know how to send an email?

Answer (score 0):

## haven't tested but this should solve your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mail::Sendmail;

open my $fh, '<', 'output.log' or die "could not open file output.log !$";

while (my $line = <$fh>) { # read the content of the file line by line
      # match and capture balance and the email address
      my ($balance, $to_email) = $line =~ /(\d+)\s+(\S+)/;
      %mail = ( To      => $to_email,
                From    => 'your_eamil@address.comacine',
                Messag => "your balance is: $balance"
              );
      sendmail(%mail);
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: With some customization , Its working great. Thanks.